# Sample http url for different HTTP response codes

Tags: http, response, http-status-codes

I need to test my script against URLs with different HTTP response codes. How do I get example/sample existing URLs for say response codes 300 or 303 or 307 etc.?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [httpbin](https://httpbin.org/) for that purpose.

For instance:

- https://httpbin.org/status/300 will return a 300 response code
- https://httpbin.org/status/303 will return a 303 response code
- etc...